# How do I redirect to an external URL in new tab by using RedirectResponse or TrustedRedirectResponse?

Tags: routes

I need to use TrustedRedirectResponse on my site and open the external url in new tab?How can it possible in drupal 8

Comment: Unless you implement a nasty JS-based solution, that's not possible. Server-based redirects cannot control the browser in that way.

Comment: Thanks,I got this with javascript.

Comment: Could you provide your answer to the question here?